# CopyQ is not shown on system tray

Tags: 18.10

I have installed CopyQ, but when I launch it, I can't see it on the system tray. (the process is running).
Is anyone familiar with it?

Comment: Have the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Server auto-starts, but it seems that the tray app does not start, so no icon in tray.  If I manually run copyq from terminal then it becomes visible.
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit.